# Application crashes while [self.view popViewController animated:YES]

Tags: iphone

application get crashed while invoking [self.view popViewController animated:YES], any reason why this happens ?????

Answer (score 0):

If you have push any viewcontroller then only u can pop the controller.

There may be a some problem in **viewWillAppear** method of the pop controller.

Answer (score 0):

before pop the controller that controller must be release all of the resources that used.so that in ur dealloc method do some research.or else u will be release the any resources twice.check out this.